# Number Scanner by camera in swift

Tags: ios, swift, numbers, barcode-scanner

Is there any way to scan numbers by the camera in swift?
I just found a bunch of barcode scanner libraries but they are not what I need. Please guide me

Comment: you could create a basic AI that compares the scanned image to a series of images of different numbers, then find the one that is most similar.

Comment: yeah, I tried it in Matlab. But do you know any similar libraries to do that?

Comment: create a blob from the scanned image using js embed, then a blob from each image in the image list of numbers, then convert each to a byte array and compare the difference. @MehdiGilanpour

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Vision framework to detect where text is](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vndetecttextrectanglesrequest), and the use an [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) framework to determine what the numbers are.

Ray Wenderlich has a tutorial on how to do this using the tesseract framework here:  https://www.raywenderlich.com/163445/tesseract-ocr-tutorial-ios

There might also be some [CoreML models](https://developer.apple.com/machine-learning/) trained for OCR that you could use if you search around.

Comment: That`s it. Thank you